# Select a string for a bound string array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have bound a simple array of strings to a list.
Knockout displays this correctly.

```
<input data-bind="value: clicked" />
<ul data-bind="foreach: strArr, click: $root.selectStr">
    <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
```

When a user clicks on one of the list items, I want to populate the string I bound with the list item. However the object my click function receives, seems to be the complete knockout model.

```
function StringViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.strArr = ko.observableArray(["one", "two", "three"]);
    self.clicked = ko.observable();

    self.selectStr = function (str) {
        console.log(str);
        self.clicked(str);
    }
}
ko.applyBindings(new StringViewModel());
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BqGrR/)

How do I write my `selectStr` function so that it would display the text from the list-item; either of ["one", "two", "three"].

This felt like an easy problem to solve, but since its my first day with knockout, maybe I am missing something basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add click handler to `li` element instead of `ul`:

```
<input data-bind="value: clicked" />
<ul data-bind="foreach: strArr">
    <li data-bind="text: $data, click: $root.selectStr"></li>
</ul>
```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BqGrR/1/